# Form prevent default only with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

This is my code

```
<?php

session_start();

include('services/dbconnection.php');

// Make the connection, test for errors
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else{
    $companyid = $_SESSION['companyid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobVacancy WHERE jv_companyid = '$companyid' ORDER BY jv_createdTime DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $count = 1;
        echo "<table>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $count++ . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "Job id: " . $row['jv_jobId'] . "<br>" . "Job Title: " . $row['jv_title'] . "<br>" . "Job Post: " . $row['jv_post'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<button id='delete'>Delete</button>" . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to **delete each recode seperately without reloading the page**.

Because *this code is inside a page tab*. If page is reloaded when one record is deleted, it shows the default tab page (Profile). I want to let user to delete each record without reloading page.

It's OK to use JQuery also.

[image]

Comment: Look into jQuery AJAX and create something that let's the user delete at will, you can then use jQuery to remove the row from screen once done

Comment: Just to add - where you have the `if ($conn->connect_error) {`, you don't need the else as when the if is true, the page dies anyway

Comment: Use ajax to remove data from database and use jquery to remove element from dom.